# React, How to get computed size, style value in useLayoutEffect?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Originally, before paint on browser, I know so can't get a computed style data (ex. height, left, width value). but React useLayoutEffect's callback can access and get computed styling data. (It is still invisible(not drawing) in display)

How can I code vanila javascript like useLayoutEffect?

```
function App() {
  const testRef = React.useRef<null | HTMLDivElement>(null);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log(testRef.current?.offsetWidth);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AppWrapper>
      <div className="test-wrapper" ref={testRef}></div>
    </AppWrapper>
  );
}

 const AppWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  .test-wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
`;
```

React useLayout before render( showing in display ), get a computed size of dom.

```
<style>
  #test-box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- <div id="test-box"></div> -->

  <script>
    const textBox = document.createElement('div');
    textBox.id = 'test-box';

    // print 0
    console.log(textbox.offsetWidth);

    document.body.appendChild(textBox);
    // print 100
    console.log(textBox.offsetWidth);
  </script>
```

Vanilla code can't get a computed size before paint.

*** Self Comment ***

First render return + layoutEffect callback is sync logic
and then useEffect callback is executed async.

Later, I will find a react's core sync, async execution logic.

Comment: On one line of code, modify the dom. On the next line of code, measure the dom. On the line after that, modify the dom again. The user will not see the first one, because the browser can't paint until your code stops running.

Comment: Can you explain more what you tried to achieve

Comment: @לבנימלכה I add picture(code). Is it sufficient?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).